# How to make the storybook dynamic in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

***weather.stories.ts***

```
export default {
  title: 'Widgets/Forecast',
  component: Weather,
}
const Template: Story<any> = (args) => <Weather {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});

Default.args = {
    forecast: {
        enable: true,
        bgColor: '#2d4059',
        textColor: '#fff'
    }
    }
```

***forecast.ts***

```
export interface ForecastProps {
    forecast: {
        enable: false,
        bgColor?: string,
        textColor?: string,

   }
}
export default function Weather({ forecast, ...props }: ForecastProps) { .... }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to set the forecast enable to `true/false`.
cause in the control story book should be `{ enable: true, bgColor: '#2d4059', textColor: '#fff' }`

where it should be like this when in the storybook.
this is just example:
[image]

[image]

here's the output of mine:
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @jperl trying to separate the enable, background and textcolor to make it just like the example above

Comment: That's what you're trying to achieve, but you haven't shown where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I struct on the part of ```forecast: {
        enable: true,
        bgColor: '#2d4059',
        textColor: '#fff'
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Forcast component, the props interface should not have the nested `forecast` object, but it should rather be like this:

```
export interface ForecastProps {
  enable: boolean,
  bgColor?: string,
  textColor?: string,
};

export default function Weather(props: ForecastProps) { .... }
```

So that the Storybook can separate the different props you're having.
+ the `enable` props type should be `boolean` rather than have the value `false`.

With this, in your `.stories` file, the `Default` args should not have the nested `forecast` object as well:

```
Default.args = {
  enable: true,
  bgColor: '#2d4059',
  textColor: '#fff',
};
```

However, for the `textColor` and `bgColor` props, the stories control will be treated like a string, not like a color picker as your exemple suggests.

Comment: how'bout when I added a new object for the current ? ```current = { enable: true, bgColor: 'red' }```

Comment: Where does the `current` come from ?
The thing here is that if you define one prop with a type object (forecast in your example) in the `Default.args`, then in the storybook you'll need to provide an object (with the JSON writing), and not the elements one by one as you wanted. So in order to have the pretty controls, they need to be at the 'root' of your Default.args, and not nested